# 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ecmascript-6

I'm using node, express on backend and angular4 at client side which is giving me following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:4876/login/check. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Api for login/check is implimented as below:

```
router.get('/login/check', (req: any, res: any) => {
        let api = new ApiConnection(req, res);
        let accessCard: IAccessCard = api.getContent(Auth.ACCESS_CARD_KEY);
        if(!Auth.isValid(accessCard))
            return api.response.error();

        ChatBox.auth.isExpired(accessCard, function (err:any, isExpired: boolean) {
            if (err) return api.response.error();
            if(!isExpired) {
                api.cookie("AccessCard", accessCard);
                api.response.success(accessCard);
            }
            else {
                api.response.error();
            }
        })
    });
```

Where router definition is `const router = require('express').Router()`

Setting middleware for header and cors is as follows:

```
export class Application {
    private app:any = express();
    constructor() {
        this.setCors();
        this.setHeaders();
    }

    public getApp():any {
        return this.app;
    }

    private setCors(){
        let whitelist = ['http://localhost:4200','http://localhost:80'];
        let corsOptions = {
            origin: (origin:any, callback:any)=>{
                if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
                    callback(null, true)
                } else {
                    callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
                }
            }
        }
        this.app.use(cors(corsOptions));
    }



    private setHeaders() {
        this.app.use(function (req:any, res:any, next: any) {

            // Website you wish to allow to connect
            //res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', Config.WEB_APP_HOST);
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');

            // Request methods you wish to allow
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

            // Request headers you wish to allow
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type');

            // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
            // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

            // Pass to next layer of middleware
            next();
        });
    }
}
```

On client side I'm using Api as follows:

```
public startSession(callback: (status: boolean, result: any) => void ) {
    let self: ChatBox = this;
    /**
     * @res.result: IAccessCard
     */
    this.mApiConnection.get(Api.root+'/login/check', (res: any) => {
      if (res.status == ResponseStatus.SUCCESS) {
        self.mStorage.storeAccessCard(res.result);
        self.loadAccount(res.result);
      }
      callback(res.status, res.result);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Show the client side code

Answer (score 50, accepted):

While setting cors in corsOptions I added value credentials true it worked as follows:

```
private setCors(){
        let whitelist = ['http://localhost:4200','http://localhost:80'];
        let corsOptions = {
            origin: (origin:any, callback:any)=>{
                if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
                    callback(null, true)
                } else {
                    callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
                }
            },credentials: true
        }
        this.app.use(cors(corsOptions));
    }
```

Comment: `credentials: true` adds the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header that is required if you use `xhr.withCredentials=true` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

Comment: When using inline as in Sping controller, use this

`@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", allowedHeaders = "*", allowCredentials = "true")`

Comment: When using spring @Configuragtion class just append registry.addMapping("/**")
    .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
    .
.
    .allowCredentials(true);

Comment: @AkhileshKumar thanks buddy, your answers still helps after 5 years. Keep up with good spirits.

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error dealing with Laravel + Graphql. using `"fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0"` package I just needed to set the `supports_credentials` field to true in `config/cors.php`