# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is ''

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I, am using the SignalR features on angular 6 and asp.net core. But keep getting this error **Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.**

Did some research and found that it is CORS issue from the server side.So modified the server code.

**startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
    services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                           .AllowAnyMethod()
                           .AllowAnyHeader()
                           .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
                }));
     services.AddSignalR();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
         app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
         app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<SignalR>("/rule");
            });
}
```

**angular app**

```
ngOnInit() {
this.callSignalR()
}

    private callSignalR(): void {
        // set up the signal R
        let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(environment.baseUrl+"/rule").build();
        //start the connection 
        connection.start().then(() => connection.invoke("updateRules", this.autheService.getCurrentuser.userId));
        //Get the response from the server
        connection.on("updateRules", data => {console.log(data);}); 
      }
```

references

[Access-Control-Allow-Origin - Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48815030/access-control-allow-origin-angular-5)

['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772830/access-control-allow-credentials-header-in-the-response-is-which-must-be-t)

https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2095

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1694

https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2110

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You must allow credentials for your cors-policy because signalr is passing cookies as well.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
    services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                           .AllowAnyMethod()
                           .AllowAnyHeader()
                           .AllowCredentials()
                           .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
                }));
     services.AddSignalR();
}
```

Comment: getting an another error as Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error: Not Found

Comment: Then your hub endpoint is not valid. that is a new error, I would suggest to create a new question for that and google before.,

Comment: I've spent half the afternoon trying to figure this out and all I needed to do was add    .AllowCredentials()               Many thanks

Comment: This is what I was missing, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowCredentials()
                       .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
            }));
       services.AddSignalR();
    }


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => 
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<BroadcastHub>("/notify");
        });

     }
```

### From your angular app

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
     const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
     .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
     .withUrl(environment.baseUrl + 'notify')
     .build();

     connection.start().then( () => {
         console.log('SignalR Connected!');
         }).catch( (err) => {
             return console.error(err.toString());
         });
      // BoradcastMessage is the name of the function in your SignalR 
      // interface.
     connection.on('BroadcastMessage', () => {
       console.log('Message from server');
     });
 }
```