# How to set up express-session in production. Express-session is not working in https

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, express-session

I have using express-session and connect-mongo for storing the session and it is working fine in the development environment. However, it is not persisting sessions in production. When I logged in I can get the session on the server by `console.log(req.sesssion)`. However, the session is undefined if I move to another url.

```js
const whitelist = ['https://example.com', 'https://www.example.com'];
const corsOptions = {
  origin(origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
    }
  }
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store,
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for the answer I have spent about a day. Finally, I found the issues causing all the headaches. The issue was related to http requests. I am using `axios` for the requests and by default, Axios does not fetch send or receive any cookies. To be able to work cookies I needed to pass Axios config options.`{withCredentials: true}` for every requests that I made. Thanks to the [post author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002444/make-axios-send-cookies-in-its-requests-automatically).

```js
Axios.post(url, data, { withCredentials: true })...
```

However, that lead me to another issue.

> "The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the
>   response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials
>   mode is 'include'."

Then I have added `credentials: true` to my cors() module [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772830/access-control-allow-credentials-header-in-the-response-is-which-must-be-t).

```js
const corsOptions = {
  origin(origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
    }
  },
  credentials: true
};
```

Now My project is live and serving users to make their lives easier :).